# Installing Ubuntu 16 and stuck at boot checks

Tags: system-installation

so I am a total noob of Linux,Ubuntu and this forum so I apologize beforehand if my question is stupid, not complete or flawed in anyway.

I am trying to install a GUI version of Ubuntu on a High performance workstation. I include the specs cause they may be the problem.
I cannot boot into any normal Ubuntu desktop installation, on DVD it gets stuck on flashing cursor, with USB it goes further but gets stuck during system checks at usb hubs at the line "OHCI driver platform" and wont go further.
Trying Ubuntu server, it boots instantly into installation but my customer insists on GUI. can anybody guide me? thanks.

Specs for the workstation are:
Asus Z10PE-DWS16 Motherboard

2x Intel Xeon E5-2620v4 CPUs

128 GB of Ram DDR4 2133 MHz

Nvidia P5000 GPU by PNY

and a 500 GB SSD

Comment: post pictures of what's on the screen

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly but did you use the same iso for both the usb and dvd? It might be corrupted, this has induced rage a few times for me.

Download the image, run a hash check and then try to install again with the usb.

Also is your SSD by any chance an nvme disk? Ubuntu has trouble with some of the newer hardware.

Comment: Could you take the time to improve your answer by [including](https://askubuntu.com/posts/985408/edit) the essential steps and commands to run.